Questions About Logic Analyzers: Mixing Digital and Analog Signals
I recently became interested in logic analyzers, particularly those like the Saleae models that can sample both digital and analog signals on the same channel. I understand that for analog signals, an anti-aliasing filter (like a 6th order Butterworth filter) is used to eliminate high-frequency noise before the signal is sent to the ADC for conversion to digital. There’s also a high-speed comparator for detecting events like rising and falling edges.
I have a couple of questions:

For digital signals, can I run them through the same circuit? I couldn’t find a definitive answer, but it seems logical. My concern is that this might introduce some noise into the signal.

Are there any additional filters or circuits that are used before or after the anti-aliasing filters?



I am having difficulty understanding the question in a way to answer it. Simply because if you have a digital input and analog input on a same digital signal, you get a digital waveform and an analog waveform of the same signal. For Q1, what do you mean by running a signal through same circuit, because analog and digital inputs are two separate circuits already? For Q2, how could we know how these products work, unless we have schematics available? There may be RF filter but again all filtering may slow signal edges and degrade the digital edge detection.

@ZEPHYRUS SUTDIO it seems like your questions should be directed at the sales support staff of the manufacturer of these products. They will be the best informed afterall it is their product, and they may already have the best answer to your question. This forum is for the discussion of electronic engineering . The Saleae forum would be more suitable for their specific products....
